# Let $V$ be the open set in the $xy$-plane. Show that the set is a regular surface.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

Let $V$ be the open set in the $xy$-plane. Show that the set
\begin{align*}
\left\lbrace (x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\, | \, z=0 \text{ y } (x, y)\in V \right\rbrace 
\end{align*}
is a regular surface.

Let be $\textbf{x}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a function given by
\begin{align*}
\textbf{x}(u, v)=(u, v, 0)
\end{align*}
Then $\textbf{x}(V)$ is exactly the given surface. The function $\mathbf{x}$ is continuously differentiable because its component functions are polynomials. Also,
\begin{align*}
\textbf{x}_u(u, v) &= (1, 0, 0) \\
\textbf{x}_v(u, v) &= (0, 1, 0)
\end{align*}
These two vectors are obviously linearly independent for all $(u, v)\in V$. Condition 1 is clearly satisfied and condition 3 also offers no difficulty. Finally, every point $(x, y, z)$ of the set is in the image by $\textbf{x}$ of the single point $(u, v)=(x, y)\in V$. For this reason $\textbf{x}$ is injective and now it would only be necessary to give an argument to say that $\textbf{x}^{-1}$ is continuous. Thus the given set is a regular surface.

Well, I don't know if my idea is right or how would you solve it?

Comment: What are conditions 1 and 3? To conclude, note that $f\colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x,y,z) = (x,y)$ offers a left inverse to $\mathbf{x}$

Comment: Open in what topology? What definition of regular are you using?